# insertion sort in Introduction to Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, insertion-sort

in an Introduction to Algorithm 2nd edition, I found insertion sort pseudo code

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1   for j <- 2 to length[A]
2       do key <- A[j]
3          //Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1 □ j - 1].
4          i <- j - 1
5          while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6           do A[i+1] <- A[i]
7              i <- i -1
8          A[i + 1] <- key
```

but I can't understand how swap works here.

I think it needs a swap operation like this

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1   for j <- 2 to length[A]
2       do key <- A[j]
3          //Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1 □ j - 1].
4          i <- j - 1
5          while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6           do temp <- A[i+1]
7              A[i+1] <- A[i]
8              A[i] <- temp
9              i <- i -1
10         A[i + 1] <- key
```

did I get something wrong?
please help

Comment: For understanding, it helps to trace things out on paper, line by line, and keep track of the variables and the array on every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in insertion sort is not a swap.

It is moving each item greater than the one you want to insert up by one index working down from the end of the currently sorted section, and then inserting the new record at the correct place after the old value is moved up.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't understand how swap works here.

No it does not.

The value is already saved in the beggining.

It saves `j` and then shifts all the other elements until it finds the proper place

Answer (score 1):

The code is doing a "multi-swap", more precisely a rotation of a k elements by one position, in-place. This takes a single auxiliary `key` variable, like a swap does.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem. Below is the code in C which implements the above pseudo-code correctly.

The tricky part about this was that the pseudo code is using 1-based array notations unlike most programming languages!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int A[] = { 50, 20, 10, 40, 60, 30 };
  int j, key, len, i;
  len = (sizeof(A)) / (sizeof(A[0]));

    for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {  <-- Change here
      key = A[j];
      // Insert key into the sorted sequence A[1 .. j - 1].
      i = j - 1;
      while (i >= 0 && A[i] > key) {  <-- Change here
          A[i + 1] = A[i];
          i--;
      }
      A[i + 1] = key;
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < len; z++) {
       printf("%d ", A[z]);
    }
   printf("\n");
 }
```